# Add Manufacturer in Related product grid in magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, grid-layout

I want to add the manufacturer column in the Product edit form section in the backend in the Related Products, Up-Sells, and Cross-Sells tab.

I have to also add a filter for the manufacturer in the product grid.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below file...

**`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Related.php`**

for above file to effect code in Related, Up-sell and cross-sell products grid list in product tab.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: create di.xml @ app/code/ABC/XYZ/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="add_manufacturer_column_to_related_upsells_crosssells_product_grid" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">ABC\XYZ\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Manufacturer</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

**Step:2 Create Data Provider Class Manufacturer.php**
@ app/code/ABC/XYZ/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Manufacturer.php

```
<?php

namespace ABC\XYZ\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductLinkRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\DynamicRows;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Number;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Modal;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image as ImageHelper;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;

class Manufacturer extends Related
{
    private static $previousGroup = 'search-engine-optimization';

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private static $sortOrder = 90;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */

    /**
     * @var LocatorInterface
     * @since 101.0.0
     */
    protected $locator;

    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     * @since 101.0.0
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @var ProductLinkRepositoryInterface
     * @since 101.0.0
     */
    protected $productLinkRepository;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     * @since 101.0.0
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var ImageHelper
     * @since 101.0.0
     */
    protected $imageHelper;

    /**
     * @var Status
     * @since 101.0.0
     */
    protected $status;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetRepositoryInterface
     * @since 101.0.0
     */
    protected $attributeSetRepository;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @since 101.0.0
     */
    protected $scopeName;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @since 101.0.0
     */
    protected $scopePrefix;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Price
     */
    private $priceModifier;

    /**
     * @param LocatorInterface $locator
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param ProductLinkRepositoryInterface $productLinkRepository
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param ImageHelper $imageHelper
     * @param Status $status
     * @param AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSetRepository
     * @param string $scopeName
     * @param string $scopePrefix
     */
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        ProductLinkRepositoryInterface $productLinkRepository,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        ImageHelper $imageHelper,
        Status $status,
        AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSetRepository,
        $scopeName = '',
        $scopePrefix = ''
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->productLinkRepository = $productLinkRepository;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->status = $status;
        $this->attributeSetRepository = $attributeSetRepository;
        $this->scopeName = $scopeName;
        $this->scopePrefix = $scopePrefix;
    }


    /**
     * Prepare data column
     *
     * @param ProductInterface $linkedProduct
     * @param ProductLinkInterface $linkItem
     * @return array
     * @since 101.0.0
     */
    protected function fillData(ProductInterface $linkedProduct, ProductLinkInterface $linkItem)
    {
    
        return [
            'id' => $linkedProduct->getId(),
            'thumbnail' => $this->imageHelper->init($linkedProduct, 'product_listing_thumbnail')->getUrl(),
            'name' => $linkedProduct->getName(),
            'status' => $this->status->getOptionText($linkedProduct->getStatus()),
            'attribute_set' => $this->attributeSetRepository
                ->get($linkedProduct->getAttributeSetId())
                ->getAttributeSetName(),
            'sku' => $linkItem->getLinkedProductSku(),
            'manufacturer' => $linkedProduct->getData('manufacturer'),
            'price' => $linkedProduct->getPrice(),
            'position' => $linkItem->getPosition(),
        ];
    }


    /**
     * Retrieve grid
     *
     * @param string $scope
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     * @since 101.0.0
     */
    protected function getGrid($scope)
    {
        $dataProvider = $scope . '_product_listing';

        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-wide',
                        'componentType' => DynamicRows::NAME,
                        'label' => null,
                        'columnsHeader' => false,
                        'columnsHeaderAfterRender' => true,
                        'renderDefaultRecord' => false,
                        'template' => 'ui/dynamic-rows/templates/grid',
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows-grid',
                        'addButton' => false,
                        'recordTemplate' => 'record',
                        'dataScope' => 'data.links',
                        'deleteButtonLabel' => __('Remove'),
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                        'map' => [
                            'id' => 'entity_id',
                            'name' => 'name',
                            'status' => 'status_text',
                            'attribute_set' => 'attribute_set_text',
                            'sku' => 'sku',
                            'manufacturer' => 'manufacturer',
                            'price' => 'price',
                            'thumbnail' => 'thumbnail_src',
                        ],
                        'links' => [
                            'insertData' => '${ $.provider }:${ $.dataProvider }'
                        ],
                        'sortOrder' => 2,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                'record' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'componentType' => 'container',
                                'isTemplate' => true,
                                'is_collection' => true,
                                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record',
                                'dataScope' => '',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'children' => $this->fillMeta(),
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve meta column
     *
     * @return array
     * @since 101.0.0
     */
    protected function fillMeta()
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->getTextColumn('id', false, __('ID'), 0),
            'thumbnail' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                            'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/dynamic-rows/cells/thumbnail',
                            'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => 'thumbnail',
                            'fit' => true,
                            'label' => __('Thumbnail'),
                            'sortOrder' => 10,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'name' => $this->getTextColumn('name', false, __('Name'), 20),
            'status' => $this->getTextColumn('status', true, __('Status'), 30),
            'attribute_set' => $this->getTextColumn('attribute_set', false, __('Attribute Set'), 40),
            'sku' => $this->getTextColumn('sku', false, __('SKU'), 50),
            'manufacturer' => $this->getTextColumn('manufacturer', false, __('Manufacturer'), 65),
            'price' => $this->getTextColumn('price', true, __('Price'), 60),
            'actionDelete' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'additionalClasses' => 'data-grid-actions-cell',
                            'componentType' => 'actionDelete',
                            'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                            'label' => __('Actions'),
                            'sortOrder' => 70,
                            'fit' => true,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'position' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'dataType' => Number::NAME,
                            'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                            'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => 'position',
                            'sortOrder' => 80,
                            'visible' => false,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
    
}
```